# "having soiled" versus "soiling"

Tags: tense, verbs

> He took pictures of his children having soiled their pants.

I am wondering if this is the best way to say it.

Do we use "**having soiled**" or do we use "**soiling**", because soiling seems to imply he took pictures while they just started soiling and not after the fact, while "**having soiled**" means it occurred after the fact. Is there a better way to say this?

Comment: A weird thing to do and a strange thing to want to communicate.  It also has a dangling participle (who did the soiling? I assume the children, but the sentence says that "He" soiled his children's pants)  The better way to say it is not to say it at all! Could you provide a situation in which you would need to communicate this?  A family court?

Comment: The father took pictures thinking it wouldn't embarrass his children.

Comment: "When they had soiled..."

Comment: While perfectly understandable to this AmEng speaker, another way to say it would be "...children after they had soiled their pants." I don't know if you are aware but "soiled their pants" generally means peed or pooped not just gotten dirty playing.